# Embedded swf file in Rails app returns error

Tags: html, ruby, flash, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm new to Rails, and I have a problem getting my swf file to work properly in my rails app. My swf file works properly when I open it alone. It also works properly when I embed it in a random html file.

Now, I embedded my swf file, 'game.swf' into 'hello.html.erb', one of the files in my 'app/views' folder:

```
<embed src="<%= asset_path('game.swf') %>"
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
       allowScriptAccess="always" />
```

My swf file loads properly, but the problem arises when it has to load a text file, 'map1.txt'
Within my swf file, I have a URLLoader which was supposed to load a text file with this relative path:

```
"../txts/maps/map1.txt"
```

here is a portion of my assets folder in the rails app:

```
--assets
----swfs
------game.swf
----txts
------maps
---------map1.txt
```

When I play the swf file in my Rails app, it returns Error #2032...Stream Error.
It seems like my swf file could not locate map1.txt.

I've already tried embedding the swf file differently using the solution provided here
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/flash/v3/errorcodes, but my swf file still gives me the same error.

I thought maybe the problem had something to do with the Rails asset pipeline. I read here
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html
that Rails places assets in a whole new folder like public/assets/, and so specific paths to files such as the one above no longer work once I run the app. If that's so, how can I modify the path in my swf file so it can correctly reference my map1.txt file?

Or...My second guess was that Rails does not know that I needed the txt file for my embedded swf, so rails does not load the txt file. Do I have to modify my Rails app or do anything so that Rails will know that my swf file needs access to my map1.txt file?

Basically, I think the problem is that I could not access one asset through another asset in Rails. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Thank you!

Edit again:

Here is what cmd says:

```
Started GET "/assets/game.swf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-04 15:32:08 +0800


Started GET "/assets/map1.txt" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-04 15:32:15 +0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/map1.txt"):
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `c
all'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `ca
ll'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tag
ged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware
.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `servi
ce'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in
start_thread'


  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (28.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within
rescues/layout (148.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you show web server console output? Also, what version of Rails?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to place this... I'm using Rails 4.1.8.

Comment: The web console output is important, it should show what the server is doing when it throws the error.

Comment: So it's a simple matter of the controller can't find the file. Can you run `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile` and see if it fixes your problem?

Comment: I tried running that command in cmd, then running the app once again. It still returns the same error and prints the same thing in the web server console.

Comment: I really think it's getting confused by your path in the .swf file. Change the path in the swf file to just "map1.txt" with no relative path. I think the SWF is asking Rails for the file and Rails is looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I modified the swf as you said. Now, rails seems to be looking for the file "/map1.txt". I will edit to show the web console output once again.

Comment: Interesting, well you notice that the web server finds the .swf file even though it is not really in "/assets/game.swf" but "/assets/swfs/game.swf". I would try setting the URL to "/assets/map1.txt" and see what happens.

Comment: Again, rails still couldn't find "/assets/map1.txt"

Comment: OK, put a copy of map1.txt into public/assets folder and see what happens. I think you may have to end up storing your files in the Public folder.

Comment: Wow! That works very well. I'd have to check if there are any disadvantages when using the public/assets/ folder though. But thanks so much! :)

Comment: I'd like to write this up as an answer, but I don't feel it is the RIGHT answer. I would rather know why the asset pipeline isn't working as expected.

Comment: I agree. It seems like a strange solution to me too. I just found out that  the txt file goes missing again after I deploy the app. I'm glad the swf file works in my rails app anyway. Thanks again!

Comment: edit to my previous comment: the app actually still works after deployment after I ran `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile`. (the assets are still in the /public folder though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer is to server static assets from the `/public` folder. You can put the `.txt` file into

```
/public/txts/maps/map1.txt
```

and then reference it in the .swf file as

```
"/txts/maps/map1.txt"
```

Rails will handle the request by automatically looking in the /public... folder. Since these are static assets, that should work fine.

Rails is not blocking the .swf file from making requests. The .swf file is running in the browser, so the browser is just making absolute path requests of the web server.

Answer (score 1):

When I deploy my rails app, Beartech's above solution of transferring the maps folder to the `public/assets` is so far the best solution.

However, if I just want to run the rails app locally, I don't have to place my txt files in the `/public` folder.

The file path in the swf file should be set to `"assets/maps/map1.txt"`, not any of these that I attempted: "../txts/maps/map1.txt", "assets/map1.txt" or just "map1.txt".

The console reads:

```
Started GET "/assets/game.swf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-04 19:30:00 +0800

Started GET "/assets/maps/map1.txt" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-04 19:32:23 +0800
```

It IS interesting that the console does not mention the name of the subdirectory `swfs` or `txts`.
This is because Rails transfers all the contents of subdirectories of `app/assets` into one big folder `public/assets/` during compilation. Rails then does a search in the `public/assets/` folder.

If I do a precompile with the `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile` command, then
my `public/assets` folder will contain the following:

```
--public/assets
----game.swf
----maps
------map1.txt
```

That is why the relative path to the text file is now `"maps/map1.txt"`.

Comment: Every time I think I understand the asset pipeline, I don't. It seems so simple.